# Unable to run OpenLDAP on freeBSD

Tags: freebsd, openldap

I've installed openLDAP on my FreeBSD machine. When I try to run the service, I get the following error.

```
Unrecognized database type (mdb)
```

Can someone point me towards what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you use the package or the port? If you used the port, was the MDB option enabled?

Comment: @ThomasWeinbrenner I used ports. I am guessing that the MDB option is not enabled by default. I do not remember being prompted to enable this during the installation process

Comment: According to [this](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/net/openldap24-server/Makefile?revision=396801&view=markup) it is a default option. Try to enable it and  build the port again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. There're some options in the `slapd.conf` file which are commented out. Look for:

```
# Load dynamic backend modules:
modulepath      /usr/local/libexec/openldap
# moduleload    back_mdb
# moduleload    back_ldap
```

Uncomment the `back_mdb` line and that should sort it.